# Как удалить начальные и конечные пробелы в Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, office

После переноса данных из Excel в отчет Word мне надо выстроить их столбцом для удобства восприятия. После вставки значения гуляют как лесенка. Все дело в начальных пробелах. Для решения этой проблемы я решил использовать два цикла в VBA:

```
Sub RemoveLeadingSpaces()
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Do While Selection.Start < Selection.End
        Do
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
            firstCharacter = Selection.Characters(0).Text
            If firstCharacter = " " Then
                Selection.Characters(0).Delete
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine
    Loop
End Sub
```

Идея в том, что один цикл должен проходить по странице и искать начальные пробелы, а другой должен удалять. Так до тех пор, пока все начальные пробелы не будут удалены.

Проблема в том, что после запуска этого макроса ничего не происходит.

Comment: Можно привести пример текста документа с пробелами?

Comment: Не надо работать с Selection. Работай с Range.Paragraphs. И вместо поиска отдельных пробелов - просто Trim(). И никаких Exit.

Comment: если на один раз, то можно сделать и без скрипта, средствами самого ворда через найти-заменить